# I want to show my product video in the first position in carousel

Tags: magento2, product-images, product-video, owl-carousel

I want to show a video of the product in the first position from the carousel.

When the user clicks on the product If the product contains video in the carousel slider.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [link](https://www.magedelight.com/resources/how-to-upload-videos-using-youtube-api-key-in-magento-2/) will be helpful

You can select the role for your video, when you add the video from admin panel just like product image.